# What happens in Peterson's problem if one process only wishes to use the critical section once?

Tags: algorithm, operating-system

So for Peterson's solution:

```
flag[0]   = 0;
flag[1]   = 0;
turn;

P0: flag[0] = 1;                                       
    turn = 1;                                               
    while (flag[1] == 1 && turn == 1)                        
    {                                                       
           // busy wait                                             
    }                                                                                      
    // critical section                                     
       ...                                                     
    // end of critical section                              
    flag[0] = 0;   

P1: flag[1] = 1;                                       
    turn = 0;                                               
    while (flag[0] == 1 && turn == 0)                        
    {                                                       
           // busy wait                                             
    }                                                                                      
    // critical section                                     
       ...                                                     
    // end of critical section                              
    flag[1] = 0;
```

Imagine both processes are ran at the same time but P1 is a bit slower and sets turn = 0.
P0 is now allowed to enter the critical section and when done it sets the flag[0] = 0; indicating that P0 does not want to enter the critical section anymore. But what if P0 now exits the while loop?

turn is still set to 0 no?
Would this not mean that P1 is now stuck in the wile loop.

Comment: The condition is using `&&`, so the `while` loop in P1 continues to run as long as `flag[0] == 1` **AND** `turn == 0`. When P0 sets `flag[0]` to 0, the while loop in P1 exits.

Comment: @user3386109 yeah that is what I mean, it is now stuck in the wile loop no? And wouldn't this mean that it does not satisfy the progress rule of the critical section?

Comment: No, P1 is not stuck. As soon as P0 sets `flag[0] = 0`, the loop in P1 is done, and P1 enters it's critical section.

Comment: @user3386109 But how does it exit the loop tho, turn is still set to 0?

Comment: You don't seem to understand the concept of [logical AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction). Both conditions need to be true for the loop to continue. After P0 sets `flag[0] = 0`, the first condition is false, so it doesn't matter what `turn` is.